# Codeigniter Uri string values getting wrong

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, uri

The codeigniter uri string value with hypen was replaced with underscore in query.

For example : http://domain.com//demo1/index.php/class/method/test-product

The URI : test-product was passed into the query with test_product , so the value is empty in the query result.

How to avoid this problem

Comment: You can use use `$this->uri->segment(3)` if it is always test-product. It will not make any difference what ever you do with `test-product`

Answer (score 1):

Use [URI Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/uri.html) to get the uri segment value like this way:

```
$this->uri->segment(n);
```

here `$this->uri->segment(3)` will return `test-product`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it

```
$data = str_replace('_','-',$data);
```